# Getting this ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer when hitting GET request in API

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am using angular with drf whenever i send some GET request i got response in my console like this and the error in console start increasing

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.43.129', 58645)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/chip/Documents/Git/apis_gifola/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/chip/Documents/Git/apis_gifola/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Are you using the built-in `runserver` command, or `gunicorn` etc?

Comment: its happening in both on staging server and local server too..
as in local server i can see this error and every time it happens the whole angular app reload and thanks for replying